# Where can I find added category related pages in folder in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, category, code

I am new to magento 2.I have added 1 category "Clothes" from admin panel.
On front, it shows this url :http://localhost/magento-demo/clothes.html

where Can I find this clothes.html page ? 
there is no code folder inside app folder .
Where can I see the code for fetching these categories ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fetch category page code from,

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/category

folder.

here you can fetch your code.

Comment: But there are so many views (.phtml files )in that folder .How will I know which page is loaded ? Also, where can i get the code to fetch them?

Comment: using template path hints open in magento you can find related file

Comment: & controller path?

Comment: inside controller folder /module-catalog/Controller/Category

Comment: you mean view.php right ?thanks. One last question ,If I need to customise it, do i have to write my own module with same name  right ??

Comment: yes you have to override into your custom module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41849/discussion-between-user2431224-and-rakesh).